# Email-box shows at "random" place

Tags: html, css, textbox, margin, padding

I'm currently busy with this informatics project(Build a sample datingsite) of mine. The problem is that I'm having some troubles with getting everything in the right place. Everything went fine until my email-box showed up at the wrong place(However, Dreamweaver displays it as I want it). I don't know how, I don't know why but I think it has to do something with my margins or paddings. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

HTML+CSS(many words are dutch and I am a beginner to this all, so please don't expect a high quality code. I do have my HTML and CSS in separate files in my real project.):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;       
}

body {
    background-color:#666;
    font-family:corbel; 
}

.container {
    width: 1240px;  
}

#HomeLeftSideRegister {
    float:left;
}

.Form {
    width: 1240px;
    height: 600px;  
    display:block;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 111px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#Registreernu {
    margin-left:45px;
    color: #3c948b;
    font-size: 70px;        
}

#Home-email {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;       
    margin-left: 245px;

}


.Email {
    color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;

}

#useremail {
    height: 22px;
    width: 281px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 149px;    
}

.Gender {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 155px;
    width: 130px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

#gender-1 {
    margin-left:150px;  

}

.Radiolabel {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.Roundbutton {
    background-color: #3c948b;
    height: 74px;
    width: 196px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float:none;
    margin-left:193px;
}

#input {
    margin-top: 220px;


}

#BlouseManImage {
    float:right;
    margin: 44px 70px auto auto;    
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="Content" class="Container">

    <section id="Home-Register">
        <form class="Form" action="#" >
            <div id="HomeLeftSideRegister">
                <div id="Registreernu">REGISTREER NU</div>
                <h2 id="Home-email">EMAIL:</h2>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="Email" id="useremail"/>
              <fieldset class="Gender" id="gender-1">

              <H3>IK BEN EEN:</H3>

              <div class="Radiolabel">  
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="amman" class="styled-radio" value="Man"/>
                    Man
                </label> <br />

                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="amvrouw" class="styled-radio" value="Vrouw"/>
                    Vrouw                
                </label>
               </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="Gender">

              <H3 class="">IK ZOEK EEN:</H3>

              <div class="Radiolabel">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="likeman" class="styled-radio" value="Man"/>
                    Man
                </label> 
                <br />

                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="likevrouw" class="styled-radio" value="Vrouw"/>
                    Vrouw   
                </label> 
                  <br />

                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="likebeide" class="styled-radio" value="Beide"/>
                    Beide
                </label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div id="input">
                <input type="submit" value="GA VERDER" class="Roundbutton">
            </div>


          </div>
                <div id="BlouseManImage"><img src="Images/Man_Registreer.jpg" alt="Ik probeer het gewoon" height="535" width="577"  />
            </div>          
        </form>       
    </section>


    <section id="reclame">



    </section>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you're another victim of the 'float' rule :-)

Your `.Gender` divs have `float: left` and it makes these divs go to the left and your email field had to appear to the right.

I solved it making the email field also float, so it gets there first... Also, I had to separate your 2 divs for gender because they are different and one needed to clear the float above so it goes to the row below.

Also, the html had to have name the 2 separated div classes, for `GenderBen` and `GenderZoek`.
(I don't know Dutch but I presume it stands for what you are and what you're looking for :-D)

The modified code is:

```
.Email {
    color:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    float: left;
}
.GenderBen {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 155px;
    width: 130px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.GenderZoek {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 155px;
    width: 130px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

And the html with the changed divs:

```
          <fieldset class="GenderBen" id="gender-1">
          <H3>IK BEN EEN:</H3>
          <div class="Radiolabel">  
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="amman" class="styled-radio" value="Man"/>
                Man
            </label> <br />
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="amvrouw" class="styled-radio" value="Vrouw"/>
                Vrouw                
            </label>
           </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="GenderZoek">
          <H3 class="">IK ZOEK EEN:</H3>
          <div class="Radiolabel">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="likeman" class="styled-radio" value="Man"/>
                Man
            </label> 
            <br />
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="likevrouw" class="styled-radio" value="Vrouw"/>
                Vrouw   
            </label> 
              <br />
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="likebeide" class="styled-radio" value="Beide"/>
                Beide
            </label>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Check the result here http://jsfiddle.net/yn8bjfbf/